# Edit the default 'post' custom post type arguments

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm editing the default WordPress "post" custom post type, to add a "news" prefix before the single posts. I've used the `register_post_type_args` hook to add my args. It does work however it doesn't redirect the default permalink.

For example the post;

`.com/news/hello-world` Valid

`.com/hello-world` Valid

I don't want the 2nd example to valid and rewrite it to have the permalink prefix `news`.

```
function custom_post_prefix( $args, $post_type ) {
  if( 'post' == $post_type ) {
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'news';
  }
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'custom_post_prefix', 10, 2 );
```

*Note I have a number of custom post types added so using the admin interface is not usable in this case.

Comment: You can just do this in Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Please read the full question, this is not possible within Settings > Permalinks because it will add the prefix to all my other custom post types.

Comment: Set `with_front` to `false` on those post types.